# Incomplete Frege Documentation

Tags: documentation, frege

The javadocs at http://www.frege-lang.org/doc/index.html seem to be missing quite a bit (namely, no frege.prelude package), and does not seem very up to date. Might there be a good documentation for Frege hidden in plain sight somewhere?

Comment: Is [this one](http://www.frege-lang.org/doc/fregedoc.html) better? I don't use Frege but found the link on their github page. It does have a frege.prelude package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have seen is the API doc of the runtime classes, which is really minimal since the typical Frege user will not work with those.

Thomas correctly pointed to the library documentation.

In addition, there is "Hoogle" support for Frege: http://hoogle.haskell.org:8081/ where you can search the API.

All is linked from the Frege home page.

Hope that helps.

Comment: When trying to interoperate Java with Frege, Frege sometimes expects me to provide objects that have weird types like `Func.U<α, >` or something.

Comment: That's the Frege way of mapping function types to Java since the latest compiler versions 3.24.x When you work with Frege only, you should never see this. Only when you want to use a Frege function type in Java code, you have to deal with this. What is it that you want to call? (and btw, you best use an editor/font that displays all Unicode chars)

Comment: I have a data type in Frege representing a generic Java type (say `Function<T, R>`), and I can't seem to get the `apply` method right. Frege compiles `native apply {α, β} :: Mutable s FooFunc -> ST s α -> ST s β` just fine, but the function signature from the Java end looks something like `apply(α, Func.U<α, >)`.

Comment: Without seeing the whole code, it is a bit difficult to tell but you can copy the "pattern" from here: https://github.com/Frege/FregeFX/blob/master/fregefx/src/main/frege/fregefx/JavaFxUtils.fr